# How to send/receive variable length protocol messages independently on the transmission layer

Tags: embedded, protocols, network-protocols

I'm writing a very specific application protocol to enable communication between 2 nodes. Node 1 is an embedded platform (a microcontroller), while node 2 is a common computer.

Such protocol defines messages of variable length. This means that sometimes node 1 sends a message of 100 bytes to node 2, while another time it sends a message of 452 bytes.
Such protocol shall be independent on how the messages are transmitted. For instance, the same message can be sent over USB, Bluetooth, etc.

Let's assume that a protocol message is defined as:

```
| Length (4 bytes) | ...Payload (variable length)... |
```

I'm struggling about how the receiver can recognise how long is the incoming message. So far, I have thought about 2 approaches.

**1st approach**

The sender sends the length first (4 bytes, always fixed size), and the message afterwards.
For instance, the sender does something like this:

```
// assuming that the parameters of send() are: data, length of data
send(msg_length, 4)
send(msg, msg_length - 4)
```

While the receiver side does:

```
msg_length = receive(4)
msg = receive(msg_length)
```

This may be ok with some "physical protocols" (e.g. UART), but with more complex ones (e.g. USB) transmitting the length with a separate packet may introduce some overhead. The reason being that an additional USB packet (with control data, ACK packets as well) is required to be transmitted for only 4 bytes.
However, with this approach the receiver side is pretty simple.

**2nd approach**

The alternative would be that the receiver keeps receiving data into a buffer, and at some point tries to find a valid message. Valid means: finding the length of the message first, and then its payload.
Most likely this approach requires adding some "start message" byte(s) at the beginning of the message, such that the receiver can use them to identify where a message is starting.

Comment: Could `msg_length` and `msg` be part of the same buffer?

Comment: @domen What do you mean exactly? In theory, msg_length is the first field of the message (it can be treated as a simple header), followed by the payload (the msg content). Sending/receiving it into 1 or separate buffers does not really matter, I believe. As long as the sender and the receiver know where it is. Or maybe I didn't understand the question...

Comment: If you send them in one buffer, you remove the downside of "1st approach" (if I understood the downside correctly - two sends instead of one)

Comment: We have created a basic protocol design to be agnostic of its transmission medium (serial, USB-serial, Bluetooth, etc.) for our project; a start marker of a fixed size, message id of a fixed size, message size of a fixed size to keep track of the expected payload size, the payload itself using the Protobuf, the CRC32 checksum, and \r\n as its end marker. The transmitting side is always easy. But, the receiving side is more difficult depending on how the transmission medium works, especially for the Bluetooth.

Comment: Bluetooth breaks every packet in several frames of varying size at will, so we need to reassemble the whole packet correctly by finding the start marker and slowing capture the frames until the end marker. Once we reassemble the frames into a buffer, we can start parsing it according to the protocol design, starting with the message id, then the message size where we use the size to verify the payload size to read it and CRC32 checksum to verify the payload content).

Comment: The following link may be interesting to read https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-packet-concept-high-level-synchronization-for-data-links/

Comment: if you divide your system into multiple transmission layers, then the lower layer must take care of overhead and keep your application message length intact, meaning exactly same as whatever you sent. Why should we consider that?? I agree with @domen about the approach.